# file download is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a link button named `Download` inside the hierarchical grid (**Telerik RadGrid**). i planned to download the file in the click event of that link button. every thing works fine until i placed an update panel inside the page. how can i download a word file even when the page contains an update panel. following is the code i am using :

**In the item command**

```
 If e.CommandName = "lnkdwnload" Then
    objdbconn.ExecuteNonQuerySQL(msSql)
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & myfile.Name)
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString())
    Response.WriteFile(myfile.FullName)
    Response.End()
 End If
```

**in the Item DataBound**

```
  If e.Item.ItemType = GridItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = GridItemType.AlternatingItem Then
     If e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name = "contactentry" Then
        Dim lnk As LinkButton = Nothing
        lnk = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lnkdwnload"), LinkButton)
        If lnk IsNot Nothing Then
           ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(lnk)
        End If
     End If
   End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - **you can't**.

MS AJAX requires a very strict set of rules to apply to the response, and sending a file changes the entire response, including the headers, so the browser cannot parse it.

What you can do is:

- disable AJAX for those links via client-side code (if you are using RadAjax) as shown here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-export-with-ajax-enabled.html.
- set the NavigateUrl of the links to a custom handler you can crete that will fetch the file, so instead of causing a postback they will navigate the browser frame. You can add querystring parameters that will indicate which file the handler is to return